# MySQL More Tables or More Rows

Tags: mysql, performance, load

I am working on a game that I am going to open to the public to have on their game.
The game stores lots of information (about 300 rows) per website and spends a lot of time updating values within this MySQL database.

Is it better (faster/efficient) to add a new table for every website or to just have 1000's of rows in one table and add a column "website_id" or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to add more rows in the same table and [create an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the table. An index on the `website_id` would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go for rows with a website_id. Definitely index the website_id and it should be much more efficient -- I have about 50-60 sites running on a similar concept and it is blazing fast.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps give us some more information pertaining to the kind of information you're storing and how you are going to manipulate this data?

If a single table is going to have 300+ entries for what should be a single entity, you may have a flaw in your physical database design.  Ideally, you want to keep your tables from having *too* many entries, but this is unavoidable at times.

You might also want to look into partitioning as a means of keeping your tables smaller, if you are going to have as much data as you think.

At a glance though, it appears that using a website_id would make sense.  Create a table indexing just these, and all of your additional tables can use a field referencing the website_id where required.